# how to add a file object into a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

How to add an object to an existing javascript object ?
here's a sample of an existing javascript object

```
   var dataObj = {
       TITLE : adtitle,
       DESC : addesc,
       PRICE : price,
       DISCOUNT : discount,
       CATID : maincatid,
       STATUS : adstatus,
       QUANTITY : quantity  
   };
```

now I have this file object and i want to add it to that object above.

```
File { name: "paper.jpg", lastModified: 1445433597723, lastModifiedDate: Date 2015-10-21T13:19:57.723Z, size: 54900, type: "image/jpeg" }
```

this file object is a value from a file upload input type

```
var image1 = $('#Image1').prop("files")[0];
var image2 = $('#Image2').prop("files")[0];
```

then i also need to fire a `$.post`

```
   $.post("<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/post'); ?>", { jsonData: postdata}, function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
```

all of those scripts above are triggered when I clicke a button

```
   $('#postit').click(function(e){
          //all the scripts from above
   });
```

Comment: `dataObj.FILE = /* your file object */` ?

Comment: what if I have like 5 or more File objects ? how?

Comment: `dataObj.FILES = [ file1, file2, file3 ]` having `file1`, `file2`, `file3` being `File` occurences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *add* it to an existing object, you can simply define a new property on your `dataObj`:

```
var dataObj = {
    ...
};
// other work
dataObj.FILE = $('#Image1').prop("files")[0];
```

Or, if you can do it at the time the `dataObj` is defined, you should do that:

```
var dataObj = {
   TITLE : adtitle,
   DESC : addesc,
   PRICE : price,
   DISCOUNT : discount,
   CATID : maincatid,
   STATUS : adstatus,
   QUANTITY : quantity,
   FILE : $('#Image1').prop("files")[0]
};
```

If you have multiple `File` objects, then you should instead store them as an array in your `dataObj`:

```
dataObj.FILES = $('#Image1').prop("files");
```

Or maybe you're working with them one at a time, and need to push them one-by-one into an array on your `dataObj`:

```
var dataObj = {
   TITLE : adtitle,
   DESC : addesc,
   PRICE : price,
   DISCOUNT : discount,
   CATID : maincatid,
   STATUS : adstatus,
   QUANTITY : quantity,
   FILES : []
};

// Populate the array
$('#Image1').prop("files").forEach(function(file) {
    dataObj.FILES.push(file);
});
```

Comment: what if I have 5 or more file objects?

Comment: Then you should instead have an array of objects. I'll edit in an example.

Comment: after i used the JSON.stringify(dataObj); ...the files aren't there when I console logged it in the browser

Comment: You're going to have to provide more context. When are you running this JavaScript? Are you submitting a form in between? Are you trying to access the file contents somehow? Is there AJAX? You asked a very simple question that now has an answer, but you haven't provided a **complete** scenario. I suspect you're trying to do something out of the ordinary here. You may want to ask a new question that contains a [mcve], and reference this one if you wish.

Comment: I edited my original post. maybe this time it's more understandable?...the images where gone after I used the JSON.stringify..am supposed to catch the json data in backend

Comment: @sasori: Are you familiar with AJAX-posting files from a file input type? It is actually quite a bit harder than it seems, and of it's own accord, way too broad of a task for [so], unfortunately. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/74757 for some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure if that answers your question, but the simplest answer is :

```
dataObj.FILE = image1;
```

Comment: what if I have 5+ file objects?